# Spring Rest Docs unable to add Model constraints in request fiels table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, documentation, spring-restdocs

I want to use the Contraints of my Dto model in my request fields documentation. When I use auto rest docs it works but then I have a problem with my KeycloakAuthMock. So I won't use auto rest docs as per documentation the requestfields can easily be added.

```
 @Test
    @Order(5)
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth(authorities = "ROLE_owner")
    void createProduct_RealmRoleOwner_HttpStatusCreated() throws Exception {

        MvcResult response = mockMvc.perform(post(URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testProductDto))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.created").isNumber())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(testProductDto.getName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.price").value(testProductDto.getPrice()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1L))
              .andDo(document("{methodName}",
                        Preprocessors.preprocessRequest(),
                        Preprocessors.preprocessResponse(
                                ResponseModifyingPreprocessors.replaceBinaryContent(),
                                ResponseModifyingPreprocessors.limitJsonArrayLength(objectMapper),
                                Preprocessors.prettyPrint()),

                        requestFields( fieldWithPath("name").description("Name of the product"),
                                fieldWithPath("price").description("Price of the new product")),
                        responseFields(fieldWithPath("id").description("Id of the new product"),
                                        fieldWithPath("name").description("Name of the product"),
                                        fieldWithPath("price").description("Price of the new product"),
                                        fieldWithPath("created").description("Unix timestamp when the product was created")
                                )))
                .andReturn();
```

Model:

```
@ApiModel(description = "Data transfer model for a new product.")
public class ProductDto {

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Name of the new product.")
    @NotNull(message = "name must not be null")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 10 , message = "Name length min is 2 and max is 10")
    private String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "price of the new product")
    @NotNull(message = "price must not be null")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "price min is 1")
    @Max(value = 100, message = "price max is 100")
    private Double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() { return price; }

    public void setPrice(Double price) { this.price = price; }
}
```

I tried to follow the [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-constraints) and I added the [template](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-customizing-including-extra-information). The template is used but I get a Mustache exception that contraints field is not found. As I won't document the constraints by hand who can I make spring rest docs add the constraints provided by my model?

Comment: Have you looked at using `ConstraintDescriptions` as shown in the documentation that you've linked to?

Comment: I neglected the ConstraintsDescription part. Sorry for the needless question. It works like charm now. Thank you.